# IE11 : Content-Type = false in IE11 it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The first solution than I tried
I use the method beginQuoteFileUnquoteUpload1 it created me a good boundary and good Content-Type but when I receive the file. The file is corrupted :(

```js
var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0], document.getElementById('file').files[0].name);

function beginQuoteFileUnquoteUpload1(data)
{
    // Define a boundary, I stole this from IE but you can use any string AFAIK
    var boundary = "---------------------------7da24f2e50046";
    var xhr = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
 if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  try {
   xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch(e) {
   xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 }else{
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 }
    }else{
 alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHTTPRequest...");
 return;
    }
    var body = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
             + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";'
             + 'filename="'+document.getElementById('file').files[0].name+'"\r\n'
             + 'Content-type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n'
             + data + '\r\n'
             + '--'boundary + '--';

    var url ="https://gedcreditor.mycloud.by/Myproject/ws/rest/sendemail/";
    url+=document.getElementById('file').files[0].name;
    url+="/a/a/a"; 
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + JWTtoken);//Our test server does not accept JWt, once we use AXA server, we will test the JWT
    xhr.setRequestHeader('ApiKey','lRABmnmS_H1Ej9yaowxqwEsuBbkxkgrzx-C1Jji_HfnJyKywR8NeuSkIJbhutfNg'); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            alert("File uploaded!");
    }
    xhr.send(body);
}

beginQuoteFileUnquoteUpload1(formData);
```

******************************Result**********************************

-----------------------------7da24f2e50046 -----> Ok
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";filename="servlet.pdf"
Content-type: application/pdf

---------------------------7da24f2e50046--
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7da24f2e50046 ----> OK

==================================================================================================================================================

The second Solution does work because the firewall blocked me because I don't have the same boundary below the method and results.

```js
var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0], document.getElementById('file').files[0].name);
function beginQuoteFileUnquoteUpload(data)
{
    // Define a boundary, I stole this from IE but you can use any string AFAIK
    var boundary = "---------------------------7da24f2e50046";
    var xhr = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
 if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  try {
   xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch(e) {
   xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 }else{
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 }
    }else{
 alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHTTPRequest...");
 return;
    }
    var url ="https://gedcreditor.mycloud.by/GEDCREDITOR_01_06/ws/rest/sendemail/";
    url+=document.getElementById('file').files[0].name;
    url+="/a/a/a"; 
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + JWTtoken);//Our test server does not accept JWt, once we use AXA server, we will test the JWT
   // xhr.setRequestHeader('ApiKey','lRABmnmS_H1Ej9yaowxqwEsuBbkxkgrzx-C1Jji_HfnJyKywR8NeuSkIJbhutfNg'); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            alert("File uploaded!");
    }
    xhr.send(data);
}

beginQuoteFileUnquoteUpload(formData);
```

******************************Result**********************************

Clé Valeur
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7da24f2e50046 ------> OK

-----------------------------7e018a1b2079a ------> Ko
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="servlet.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

Ç¥¾}«s

Answer (score 1):

The second method is the correct one, except you do not set the content type header. It is set automatically and correctly when you make the request with a FormData object.

Comment: it is very strange because, when we don't set the content type, the data are correct with the boundary but there is no content type in the header of the http request so that the WAF block us

Comment: Below error :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwACVkdzjcMEc3NWM1J0NF9pc0NYWERtajJrdV9TSmpqNHM0

Comment: I just tried sending a form data object in IE11 without setting the content type header and it generated the header with the boundary. I'm not sure what is causing your problem

Comment: Hi musa, thank you for your help. could you share me your test ? I will try it in my side. by the way, this is my IE version :11.0.9600.18314  
Version updates: 11.0.31 (KB3154070)
 what is yours ?